# How do functions really work in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, function

```
function [dhdt, x] = velocity(t, h)
    dhdt = -9.8 * t;
    x = 4 * t;
end
```

So this is basically my function (with filename `velocity.m`). At first I thought that what's between the brackets `[]` would be the output. When I typed in the Command Window I only got one answer.

```
velocity(1)

%//  -9.8
```

I expected to get a two-element vector containing both `dhdt` and `x`

```
velocity(1)
%//  -9.8  4
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Matlab only displays one output if you don't store them to variables... Type [dhdt,  x] = velocity(1) and you'll see both values, as well as having them stored to variables.

Also, you only get away in this case with not providing the h parameter because it's not used in the function. If you used h in velocity() and called velocity(1) it would break.

Comment: ty ! and i knew about the "h" thing but thanks ur very detailed

Comment: To elaborate on this, if you *do* want an array back instead, create the array inside of your function and return that one variable: `function y = velocity(t); y = [-9.8*t, 4*t];end`